# How to make text resist transparancy?

Tags: dreamweaver, jquery-cycle2

/// The text I'm referring to is the text inside the transparent caption boxes displayed just below my picture slider(Jquery cycle2).  The text seems to adhere to the opacity I've commanded for the box.  I'd also like the box to span the width of the slider and the text within it to be centered, but now I'm getting ahead of myself.  I would be glad to try any solutions suggested to me.  I've also included an example from another website of what Im trying to imitate.

```
 http://sff-law.ca/.


Instead, I've only been able to create the following:
```

///

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>Untitled Document</title>
   <style type="text/css">
   .cycle-slideshow, .cycle-slideshow * {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
   }


   /* overlay */
   .cycle-overlay {
    font-family: Baskerville, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    z-index: 800;
    background: black;
    color: #FFF;
    opacity: .1;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 211px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    right: auto;
    left: auto;
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    padding-left: 6px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    font-style: italic;
   }
   </style>

   <script src="jquery.cycle2.caption2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script src="jquery.cycle2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


   </head>

   <body background="KAWARTHA LAW/Pics/6a00d83452719d69e2017d41a50bc6970c.jpg">
   <div id="back">
   <div class="cycle-slideshow" 

    data-cycle-timeout=2000
    >
    <!-- empty element for overlay -->
    <div class="cycle-overlay"></div>

    <img src="Slidding/buying.gif" 
        data-cycle-title="Contracts" 
        data-cycle-desc="">
    <img src="Slidding/last-will-and-testament-and-glasses.gif" 
        data-cycle-title="Corporate" 
        data-cycle-desc="">
    <img src="Slidding/last-will.gif" 
        data-cycle-title="Wills and more wills" 
        data-cycle-desc="">
    <img src="Slidding/Top-5-Reasons-to-have-a-Will-in-PA-02-08-12.gif" 
        data-cycle-title="Good Wills" 
        data-cycle-desc="">
   </div>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Might want to define your question a little more to avoid down votes. The CSS property giving transparency is `opacity: .1;` opacity ranges from 0.0 (fully transparent), to 1.0 (fully opaque) http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/opacity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need this for newer browsers you can set the CSS to use an RGBA value, then the text will be opaque (This will work in IE9+, Chrome, Firefox, Safari):

```
.cycle-overlay{
     background-color:(0,0,0,.1);
}
```

If you need a backwards compatible solution, you can create a 1x1 PNG image with the transparency that you want, and set that as the background.

Comment: Thanks Bryan.  I used 0,0,0,.65